# How many minors are in a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to Wikipedia:

> For a matrix A, there are a total of ${\textstyle {m \choose k}\cdot {n \choose k}}$ minors of size
> k by k.
> (source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra))

This confuses me since for 3 by 3 matrices of size 2 by 2 minors, I'd assume there would be 9 minors, not [3,2] * [3,2] = 3*3 + 2*2 = 13 minors. Is there something I'm not seeing here? Thanks!

Comment: Those expression are binomial coefficients, not vectors.

Answer (score 6):

You're misinterpreting the notation. There are ${m\choose k}{n\choose k}$ many minors, where that symbol represents the choose function. That gives $3\cdot 3=9$ as desired.

To prove that this formula works, notice that choosing a minor really just consists of choosing which rows and columns to include. Then it's just an application of the definition of the choose function (choose $k$ rows out of $m$ possibilities) and the fundamental counting principle.

Comment: Thanks, I just read Matthew's answer